# Drupal 7 - Menu to UL

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

all. This question probably has a devilishly simple answer but it has kept me occupied for several hours.

I have my main menu and it's corresponding block in a Drupal site I am building. Like all other Drupal menus it contains a bunch of links to various parts of the site. I can assign it's block to a region and the menu links come out all nice and formatted with a title thing and little bullet points. The problem though is that I am making a custom theme for this website and I need to be able to work with the links without all the cruft added, preferably in something simple like an ul.

Is there any function that takes a menu and produces an ul containing all the links?

Maybe there is some way you can reduce the menu's block to just an ul.

I have been experimenting with `theme_menu_tree(...)` and `theme(...)` to no avail.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call [menu_build_tree](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_build_tree/7) and look at it's output and build a ul from it. However, despite the default menu output having loads of "cruft" it is a ul and should be themeable with CSS.

If you really want to build the menu yourself, I would reverse engineer another module that does so like [Nice Menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus)

Comment: Ok, I tried `<?php print menu_build_tree($main_menu); ?>` and it results in a huge error about SQL syntax » `PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')) ORDER BY p1 ASC, p2 ASC, p3 ASC, p4 ASC, p5 ASC, p6 ASC, p7 ASC, p8 ASC, p9 ' at line 2: ` **TRUNCATED** `(ml.menu_name IN ()) ORDER BY p1 ASC, p2 ASC, p3 ASC, p4 ASC, p5 ASC, p6 ASC, p7 ASC, p8 ASC, p9 ASC; Array ( ) in _menu_build_tree() (line 1370 of /var/www/includes/menu.inc).`

Comment: Ok, I've decided to just slice and dice the block output as you suggested. It's not very elegant or pretty and it increases page load but it works for now until I can find something better.

Answer (score 2):

I find **you can do most changes through CSS** such as setting `<H2>` titles to `display: none` and setting `<LI>` tags to `float: left` for a horizontal navbar.

But... if you want to build your own menu from the Drupal data, here is some code from a site I'm working on.  It builds a two-level menu.  I'm sure you could simplify this code even further if you need.

```
//----------- primary menu (horizontal with drop-downs) -------------------------

$params = array('max_depth' => 3);
$menu = menu_build_tree('main-menu', $params);
$variables['menu'] = $menu;

$html = '<ul>';

foreach($menu as $item_menu) { //for each main element

    $isSecondLevel = isset($item_menu['below']) && !empty($item_menu['below']);

    if ($isSecondLevel) {
        $html.= '<li>';
    } else {
        $html.= '<li class="sg">';
    }

    $html.= '<a class="topLevel" href="'.url($item_menu['link']['link_path']).'">';         
    $html .= $item_menu['link']['link_title'];
    $html .= '</a>';

    //is there any sub elements to display
    if ($isSecondLevel) {
        $html.= '<ul>';

        foreach($item_menu['below'] as $item_submenu) { //for each sub element
            $isThirdLevel=isset($item_submenu['below']) && ! empty($item_submenu['below']) ? 'main-menu-third_level' : '';

            $html.= '<li>';
            $html.= '<a href="'.url($item_submenu['link']['link_path']).'">';

            $html.= $item_submenu['link']['link_title'];

            $html.= '</a>';
            $html.= '</li>';
        }
        $html.= '</ul>';    
    }
    $html.= '</li>';
}
$html.= '</ul>';
$variables['main_menu_html'] = $html;
```

This code was placed inside `function pinkribbon_process_page(&$variables)` in `template.php`.  Menu is printed in the template by calling `<?php echo $main_menu_html ?>`

**Simon.**

P.S.  Others, please feel free to edit this code for clarity/simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to use

```
menu_tree_output
```

like this:

```
print render(menu_tree_output(menu_build_tree('main-menu', $parameters)));
```

Comment: Wow, much cleaner! Thanks for this.